# Add Points to CGPath Loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, sprite-kit

I am developing a game that requires a character `SKNode *character` to "randomly" move around an `SKScene` by following a randomly generated path. My question, is how can I effectively and efficiently **edit** or **extend** this path so that the character is always following a never ending path?

Here is an outline with some code snippets of how I am approaching this:

**1.** Create a `CGMutablePathRef` that will represent the path for the character to follow.

Here is the method that I am using to generate the path:

```
 - (void)createPath {
    // cgpath declared outside of this method to be retained
    cgpath = CGPathCreateMutable();

    // For simplicity, I am only dealing with positive random numbers for now 
    CGPoint s = CGPointMake(character.position.x, character.position.y);
    CGPoint e = CGPointMake([self randomNumber] + character.position.x, [self randomNumber] + character.position.y);
    CGPoint cp1 = CGPointMake([self randomNumber] + character.position.x, [self randomNumber] + character.position.y);
    CGPoint cp2 = CGPointMake([self randomNumber] + character.position.x, [self randomNumber] + character.position.y);
    CGPathMoveToPoint(cgpath, NULL, s.x, s.y);
    CGPathAddCurveToPoint(cgpath, NULL, cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, e.x, e.y);


    SKAction *planeDestroy = [SKAction followPath:cgpath asOffset:NO orientToPath:NO duration:5];
    [character runAction:planeDestroy];

    CGPathRelease(cgpath);

}

- (int)randomNumber {
    return (int)(arc4random_uniform(100) + randPointRad);
}
```

**2.** Run an `SKAction` in the scene to run this method and make the character follow the path.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:5];
SKAction *bla = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [self createPath];
}];

SKAction *randomMovement = [SKAction sequence:@[wait,bla]];

[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever: randomMovement] withKey:@"randomMovementAction"];
```

**3.*** (This is step I am having trouble with) Edit / extend the current **cgpath** with newly generated random points to continuously move the character randomly around the scene.

I understand that the path that I am creating utilizes the logic shown in the below image
[image]

Providing **Points of Control (POC)**, I am able to generate a path from defined starting and stopping points.

**MY GOAL** was to add new random control points to this path, in tern redefining the end point each addition (to some new random point some X distance from the previous point, giving some sense of continuity and coverage), then removing the previous control points (to conserve memory). I am trying to use the following method:

```
CGPathApply(<#CGPathRef  _Nullable path#>, <#void * _Nullable info#>, <#CGPathApplierFunction  _Nullable function#>)
```

to edit the path by adding new points, and extending the overall path, but I am having trouble since the path is being executed by an `SKAction`, so it's already been set.

Essentially, I am trying to repeat an action that adds a new **POC** to the already defined path, forcing the path to grow without demonstrating possible sharp turns, velocity changes, or direction changes.

Currently, the character *does indeed* float around the map randomly and continuously with the provided code I have shown, but at times the character has quite unnatural movements as cgpath(1) ends, and cgpath(2) begins, and so on to cgpath(n).

So does anyone know if there is some way to achieve what I am asking (extend and cgpath without having to stop, then start a completely new path)? **OR** at least prevent the character from performing any of these sharp unappealing movements. Thanks in advance for any help at all.

**UPDATE:** My only solution that I have been able to think of as of now is to track the angle between the last control point **B1**, and the current end point **E1**, then when creating the new path, make sure the angle between **S2** and **A2** are exact opposite (same direction of motion). Like such:

[image]